# load data from different files for Split View controller

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

I have 3 examples.
but there are very many. I want from different files to upload  for example"name: file1" "category: file 2"

```
// MARK: - Properties
var detailViewController: DetailViewController? = nil
var candies = [Candy]()
var filteredCandies = [Candy]()
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController:     nil)

// MARK: - View Setup
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   // Setup the Search Controller
   searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
   searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
   definesPresentationContext = true
   searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false

   // Setup the Scope Bar
   searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["All", "Chocolate","Hard", "Other"]
   tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

   candies = [
       Candy(category:"Chocolate", name:"Chocolate Bar"),
       Candy(category:"Chocolate", name:"Chocolate Chip"),
       Candy(category:"Qukullad", name:"keks")]

   if let splitViewController = splitViewController {
       let controllers = splitViewController.viewControllers
       detailViewController = (controllers[controllers.count-1] as! 
     UINavigationController).topViewController as? DetailViewController
   }
}
```

Comment: please add more information to your question, i dont think much ppl can understand what u wanted to ask

Comment: I have extremely large data. and in 1 file is not possible to add all this informations.
i want to load data for name: file1.txt and for category: file2.txt